# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'pages' in 'D:\chat\chat2\src'

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'pages' in 'D:\chat\chat2\src'

The react can't find the pages folder in src even though it is there
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ojsn.png)

Comment: Have you tried importing `./pages` instead of `pages`?

Comment: That screenshot is no use to us. Do you have [path intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense) installed? That would help you debug your path issues.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.